# Calculated measure to detect if multiple dimension members are selected in filter

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I would like to detect if multiple members are selected in a dimension filter and if yes then nullify my measure in the olap cube. 
Something like this

```
[measures].[total users] = IIF([measures].[is multi select], null, [measures].[total users]);
```

The reason being the total users measures gives a wrong value if multiple members are selected by user. 
I tried this measure

```
[measures].[is multi select] = ISERROR([DIM 1].[DIM1 KEY].currentmember) OR 
ISERROR([DIM 2].[DIM2 KEY].currentmember).
```

But this doesn't seem to work as expected. I thought this would give me true if multiple members of dim1 and or dim2 are selected in a filter it will return true..but it always returns false. 
Any other trick?

Comment: Does total users give an #error when multiple members are selected, or does it give an unexpected, but valid, value?

Comment: it gives unexpected but valid value

Comment: Do you have any idea why?  I think the trick will be to understand why it is giving an unexpected value, and correcting your cube design so that it gives the expected value.

Comment: May be because I have default member set on both the dimensions